# how to present a popover in custom cell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

For presenting popover I am following the below code.

```
func showPopOver() {
    let secondStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil)

    viewObj =  secondStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
    viewObj.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    viewObj.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400,500)

    let popoverPresentationController = viewObj.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view //walletButton
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, button.frame.origin.y+100, 0, 0)
    presentViewController(viewObj, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK:- UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate methods... starts

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}

func prepareForPopoverPresentation(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    print("prepare for presentation")
}

func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    print("did dismiss")
}

func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
    print("should dismiss")
    return false
}
```

its working fine in normal view controller, but i need to show a popover view in custom tableview cell.

class flow like

|-`UITableViewController`

|-CustomCell:`UITableViewCell`

|-`UIButton`: button action-> here we need to show a popover with 3/4 frame value of the tableview frame.

whenever user tapped out of the popover view then dismiss the popover view.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @NaveedAhmad
 fixed customised the values of width and height.
 viewObj.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400,500)

Comment: Thanks..........